# Find $F(0)$ and $F(1)$ of a maximal-length Fibonacci series containing $303300$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I would like to find the smallest positive $F(0)$ (not 0) and the smallest positive $F(1)$ (not 0) possible of a Fibonacci sequence so that one of the terms of the Fibonacci sequence is $303 300$, this is not the conventional Fibonacci sequence, but it is the same principle for the calculus :

> F(0) = ?
> F(1) = ?
> F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) for n >=2.

I want to maximize the position of $303 300$ in the series, I want it to be as far away as possible in the series. How can I do that?

Comment: It is not perfectly clear what you are after.  If you want to optimize $F(0)$ only, you could have $F(0)=1, F(1)=303299$ and if you wanted to optimize $F(1)$ only you could do the reverse.  Surely you want to optimize them both simultaneously somehow, but how?  The sum of them?  So, really you are trying to find the minimum value of $F(2)$ given that $0<F(0),~0<F(1)$ and that there exists some $n$ for which $F(n)=303300$?

Comment: In any event, I expect the most convenient solution will be to program a script to loop through the possibilities, generating the starts of each Fibonacci-like sequence until exceeding 303300, doing so for the smaller possible pairs of initial values until having eventually found a match.  A match is eventually guaranteed, as shown by my previous comment, and each iteration will only require so many operations, it should be easily handled by any home computer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to do it with a computer, but not sure how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a generalized Fibonacci sequence continues, the ratio of its terms grows increasingly close to $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$.  Therefore, the previous term to 303300 in a maximal length sequence would be $\frac{303300}\phi\approx187450.$  From there, we can subtract the two smallest numbers to find previous terms until we reach a negative predecessor, which indicates the start of the sequence.

That done in my Google Sheet spreadsheet, here is the maximal sequence where F(15)=303330:

> 400
> 250
> 650
> 900
> 1550
> 2450
> 4000
> 6450
> 10450
> 16900
> 27350
> 44250
> 71600
> 115850
> 187450
> 303300

Comment: Mmm... something seems off.  My code found $F(0)=400,F(1)=250,F(15)=303300$.  Ah, It seems you may have used $303330$ instead

Comment: How did you find 400 and 250, that seems to be a quite plausible answer?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did wrong.  With the correct input, I agree with your code.  Editing my answer.

Comment: @AmélieTremblay dirty Javascript code that I threw together in a minute or two, not bothering with properly optimizing it.

Comment: @JMoravitz Could I see the code on Javascript I'm not familiar with this platform and I'd like to try with other numbers?

Comment: @AmélieTremblay to emphasize, my code is awful compared to Matthew's inspired answer here.  It runs significantly faster than my code, could be written to run in less than a second, even for much larger values, compared to my monstrosity which might take upwards of a minute on a slower machine.

Comment: @JMoravitz Hey, it's always a relief when brute force validates a theory.  ^_^

Answer (score 1):

For a proper pen-and-paper math approach, see Matthew Daly's answer.

Since it was requested, here is some dirty javascript code that was thrown together that confirms his results.

```
howSoonTill = function(a,b,goal){
   copa=a; copb=b;
   for(x=2;copa+copb<goal;x++){
      copb=copa+copb; copa=copb-copa;
   }
   if(copa+copb==goal){return x} 
   return 0
}
record=0;recorda=[];recordb=[];
for(a=1; a<2000; a++){
   for(b=1;b<2000;b++){
      cur = howSoonTill(a,b,303300);
      if (record<cur){
         record = cur; recorda = [a];recordb=[b]
      } else if (record == cur){
         recorda.unshift(a);
         recordb.unshift(b);
      }
   }
}
console.log(record); console.log(recorda); console.log(recordb);
```

In the interest of time, I went with the assumption that no record would be caused by starting values greater than 2000...

Running the code does return the result of a record of $15$ steps with initial values $400$ and $250$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get a meaningful lower bound: as noted in Ritam Dasgupta's (since-deleted) answer, all sequences satisfying the Fibonacci relation $S_{n+1}=S_n+S_{n-1}$ can be written in terms of the Fibonacci sequence in the form $S_n=S_1F_n+S_0F_{n-1}$. Now, since $F_n$ and $F_{n-1}$ have GCD 1 (this is provable by induction), *any* number can be written in the form $aF_n+bF_{n-1}$; the only problem is that $a$ and $b$ may not both be positive. But there's a way around this too: by the solution to the [McNugget problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) we know that for any $n$, the largest number not representable as a sum of positive multiples of $F_n$ and $F_{n-1}$ is $F_nF_{n-1}-F_n-F_{n-1}$ Since, as noted elsewhere, $F_n\approx \phi F_{n-1}$ and the quadratic term dominates, we should be looking for an $n$ such that $F_n\approx\sqrt{\phi\cdot303300}\approx 700$. Since $F_{15}=610$ (and $F_{14}=377$), and $F_{15}F_{14}-F_{15}-F_{14}$ $= 228983$, we know that there's a representation $303300=aF_{15}+bF_{14}$ with both $a$ and $b$ positive, and in fact using the identity $F_{n-1}F_{n+1}-F_n^2=(-1)^n$ we can find $a$ and $b$ explicitly: Suppose we have $303300=aF_{15}+bF_{14}$. Then $303300-aF_{15}\equiv 0\pmod {F_{14}}$, or equivalently $a=303300/F_{15}\pmod{F_{14}}$. But by the equation $F_{13}F_{15}-F_{14}^2=1$ we see that $1/F_{15}\equiv F_{13}\equiv 233\pmod{F_{14}}$ and so $303300/F_{15}\equiv 303300\cdot233\equiv 250\pmod{F_{14}}=a$ and $b=(303300-aF_{15})/F_{14}$ $=(303300-250\cdot610)/377$ = 400; thus we can take the first two terms as $S_0=b=400$ and $S_1=a=250$ and know that $303300=S_{15}$. We don't know for sure that this is the best that can be done, though; it's *guaranteed* that there's a representation of $303300$ as a positive sum of $F_{15}$ and $F_{14}$ but it's not guaranteed that there isn't a representation as a positive sum of e.g. $F_{16}$ and $F_{15}$. To be sure we would want to run the same procedure and see if the resulting values are positive or not.